# Single menu item on click moves down but keep other menu items in place

Tags: css

I have a link/button that moves down when clicked but upon doing so all other menu items move as well. How does one keep the other items in place while the button move down?

http://www.llcinpa.com/ click on Form Your LLC Now

Comment: Looks like the `:active` state on `.custom-menu-button-2` is swapping your `margin-left: 28px;` out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Funn. It is a Professional Q & A site. You need to visit [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Please Clearly specify your problem and show your effort that you have done.

Comment: I feel my problem is more easily understood by visiting the link provided and clicking on the Form Your LLC Now in the main nav menu. Very difficult to capture in words what is better relayed on live site.

Answer (score 0):

the easy answer is this:

```
#menu-main-nav li{margin-left:28px !important}
```

this way no matter what, you'll keep your margins, which are the root of the problem

Comment: margin-left:29px resolved the left/right movement but when you click the link all links move down a few pixels. 

I would like the movement to be just for the Form Your LLC Now link